# how to keep application in running mode when create and launched in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I want to keep android application run in background not in foreground when it launched. For Example, like Android Settings and Android Keyboard. Only Running Process List in display this application. Actually, this application is running in background and user can't display it in foreground.

Comment: Why dont you try to use service, here is the link http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: I try but result not satisfy.

Comment: Man how could I suppos to know what makes you satisfied? Answer specificly so that you can get proper help, if you dont know how to explain , design any image on paint and post here, or post your code what u tried till now.

Comment: sorry boss this code is not work properly.

Comment: I want to run application in background not in foreground. Also display application in running process list but not in foreground. Understand?(For Reaching on Running Process List then Go to Manage App then Go to Running Tab and display all running app)

Comment: You have to use service to solve your problem.

Comment: yes, I used service but I really want to make application running in background, not open or splash screen on screen. when I install or run(Launch) application then it is running on background not display any content and anything in home screen. But this application's process display on running process list(Manage App->Apps->Running).

Answer (score 1):

No matter what you want to do with your app, if you want it to run in the background and not getting destroyed when it isn't displayed anymore, you have to use Service.

This is the Android Developers site explaining it:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

And this is a nice tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

If your code doesn't work with a service, it's probably not the service's fault, but your code's, and you should post another question precisely explaining your problem with it.

Comment: ok man, thanx for help...I try code which u send link. thanx for help.